# How to check once for a whole bundle if $request->isXmlHttpRequest?

Tags: ajax, fosrestbundle, symfony-3.4

For a project, i use FOSrestbundle for every bundle and i have an ApiBundle where every route is called by ajax. 
On each action, i do this check:

```
if $request->isXmlHttpRequest() {
    throw ...
}
```

I look for a way to make this check only once for the whole bundle.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put here a solution for those want to do the same

In every controller of the ApiBundle, i put this annotation the be sure every route name have the same 'api_' prefix

```
/**
 * Class SomeController.
 *
 * @Route("/some", name="api_")
 */
class SomeController extends Controller
```

in a request event listener, i put this check on the KernelEvents::REQUEST event

```
$request = $event->getRequest();

if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) {
    return;
}

if ('api_' === substr($request->get('_route'), 0, 4) && !$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
    throw new MethodNotAllowedException(['ajax']);
}
```